# How to checked box check if the loop value is true in angular

Tags: angular

I my angular app I want to checkbox as checked when there loop value is true or false how can i do that i have tried many times but not success i am new in angular any body can help thanks in advance.

expected result

http://prntscr.com/obcgic

this is my response

http://prntscr.com/obcl9l

this is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Service Type</label>
         <div class="fancy-checkbox" *ngFor="let sercs of service;let i=index">
            <label>
                <input #vt="ngModel" name="types[{{sercs._id}}]" id="{{sercs._id}}" [(ngModel)]="serviceids1[sercs._id]" type="checkbox" [value]="sercs._id">
                <span>{{sercs.service}}</span>
            </label>
            <label class="float-right">
                <input *ngIf="equipmentEdit.services.is_compulsory == false" checked  type="checkbox" #stype="ngModel" name="is_compulsory[{{sercs._id}}]" id="{{sercs._id}}" [(ngModel)]="serviceids2[sercs._id]">
                <span>Is Compulsory</span>
         </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is edit function in ts file

```
 editRecord(id: any) {

        this.equipmentService.editEquipments(id).then(res => {
            this.equipmentEdit = res.data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using reactive forms? You can dynamically patch form control values that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[checked]** ="Expression" .
If Expression/value is true Then it will be checked otherwise unchecked.

```
<input #vt="ngModel" name="types[{{sercs._id}}]" id="{{sercs._id}}" 
    [checked]="sercs.is_compulsory" [(ngModel)]="serviceids1[sercs._id]" type="checkbox" [value]="sercs._id">
```

Comment: have you check response

Comment: when project not run how can i check response

Answer (score 0):

Try it, Hope it should work

```
          <label>
            <input #vt="ngModel" name="types[{{sercs._id-{{i}}}}]" id="{{sercs._id-{{i}}}}" [checked]="serviceids1[sercs._id]" type="checkbox" (change)="serviceids1[sercs._id] = $event.target.checked?true:false;">
            <span>{{sercs.service}}</span>
        </label>
```

Or you can do it very simply

```
<label>
            <input #vt="ngModel" name="sercs.is_compulsory-{{i}}"  [checked]="sercs.is_compulsory" type="checkbox" (change)="sercs.is_compulsory = $event.target.checked?true:false;">
            <span>{{sercs.service}}</span>
        </label>
```

Comment: add my second solution

Comment: when use [checked] we need not to use [(ngModel)]
if sercs.is_compulsory == true then it will be checked